# How to Convert Column into a List based on the other column in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in pyspark which is as follows:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 123      | abc   |
| 123      | def   |
| 456      | klm   |
| 789      | nop   |
| 789      | qrst  |
```

For every row in column A the column B has to be transformed into a list. The result should look like this.

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 123      |[abc,def] |
| 456      | [klm]    |
| 789      |[nop,qrst]|
```

I have tried using map(), but it didn't give me the expected results. Can you point me in the right direction on how to approach this problem ?

Comment: [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list)

Comment: Have you tried using `collect_list` from `pyspark.sql.functions`. You can write something like: `df.group_by(col("Column A")).agg(collect_list('Column B'))`. See doc in the comment that @Steven mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list),

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1.groupBy("Column A").agg(F.collect_list("Column B")).show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]